# Pandas concatenation deleting original index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to concat two dataframes using the below code. df1 is a daily update of values to the indexes in df2, which is an ongoing monthly dataset. df3 is the result that is saved.

The problem I am experiencing is that when an index value is not in df1 (no values for that particular day), it gets deleted from df3 altogether. In other words, if the index value is not in df2, then it doesn't appear in df3 at all.

How can I keep the original index of df3, so that if the index value is not in df1, it doesn't delete it? I also cannot enter `0` values, as it is relevant to the data that it is empty.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

def Monthly_aggregation_merge(month, date):

    # file to be merged
    df1 = pd.read_csv(r'Data\{}\{}\Aggregated\Aggregated_Daily_All.csv'.format(month,date), usecols=['CU', 'Parameters', 'Total/Max/Min'], index_col =[0,1])
    df1 = df1.rename(columns = {'Total/Max/Min':date}) # Change column name

    # original file that data should be merged with
    df2 = pd.read_csv(r'Data\{}\MonthlyData\July2017NEW.csv'.format(month), index_col = [0,1])
    df3  = pd.concat([df2, df1], axis=1).reindex(df1.index)

    df3.to_csv(r'Data\{}\MonthlyData\July2017NEW.csv'.format(month))
    print 'Monthly Merge Done!'
```

Comment: Remove this: `.reindex(df1.index)`

Comment: godspeed, coldspeed.

Comment: You're welcome. That's why you should understand the code first before you run it ;)